# Sobolev trace theorem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, traces

Set $Q:=\Omega\times(0,T)\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, 
where $\Omega$ is knows as a bounded domain 
with smooth boundary $\partial D$.
We choose any subdomain $D\subset Q$ 
with smooth boundary $\partial D$. 
Moreover, we suppose that there exists 
a subdomain $\omega$ of $\Omega$ 
and a subboundary $\Gamma$ of $\partial\Omega$ such that
$$
\omega\times\{0\}\subset \partial D
$$ 
and
$$
\Gamma\times(\varepsilon,T-\varepsilon) \subset \partial D,\quad \varepsilon\in(0,T).
$$

If we know three functions 
$g_0\in H^{\frac{3}{2},1}(\Gamma\times(\varepsilon,T-\varepsilon))$,
$g_1\in H^{\frac{1}{2},1}(\Gamma\times(\varepsilon,T-\varepsilon))$
and $u_0\in L^2(\omega)$.

**My question**:

Can we extend the functions $g_0,g_1,u_0$ to a function $u\in H^{2,1}(D)$ such that
$u|_{\omega\times\{0\}}=u_0$, $u|_{\Gamma\times(\varepsilon,T-\varepsilon)}=g_0$,
$\partial_\nu u|_{\Gamma\times(\varepsilon,T-\varepsilon)}=g_1$ and we have the inequality
$$
\|u\|_{H^{2,1}(D)} \le C\|g_0\|_{H^{\frac{3}{2},1}}+C\|g_1\|_{H^{\frac{1}{2},1}}+
C\|u_0\|_{L^2(\omega)}?
$$
Here $\nu$ is the outer unit normal vector of $\partial\Omega$.

Thank you very much.